# output computation in R using shiny

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to find a pattern of "GC" in different genes(strings) with a user interface using Shiny.I am using grep command of R to find the pattern but I am not able to get the correct output.Below is the code of UI.R

```
  library(shiny)
setwd("C:/Users/ishaan/Documents/aaa")
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Copy the line below to make a select box 
  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Human Gene Sequence"), 
              choices = list("CD83" = "UGGGUGAUUACAUAAUCUGACAAAUAAAAAAAUCCCGACUUUGGGAUGAGUGCUAGGAUGUUGUAAA"
                             , "SEC23A" = "UUUCACUGU"
                             , "ANKFY1" = "AAGUUUGACUAUAUGUGUAAAGGGACUAAAUAUUUUUGCAACAGCC"
                             ,"ENST00000250457"="ACUUGUUGAAUAAACUCAGUCUCC"
                             ), 
              selected = "UGGGUGAUUACAUAAUCUGACAAAUAAAAAAAUCCCGACUUUGGGAUGAGUGCUAGGAUGUUGUAAA"),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(5, verbatimTextOutput("value")),column(5, verbatimTextOutput("value2")))


))
```

Server.R

```
library(shiny)
setwd("C:/Users/ishaan/Documents/aaa")
shinyServer(function(input , output) {
  strings=input$select

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$select, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })

  output$value2 <- renderPrint({ grep("*gc*",input$value })


})
```

Comment: Missing parenthesis for grep? `renderPrint({ grep("*gc*",input$value })`, and maybe set `ignore.case = TRUE`.

Comment: What is actually your desired output. With grep it will only be `0` or `1`. The statment is also lacking two dots
`renderPrint({ grep(".*gc.*",input$value })`

Comment: I want to find the number of occurrences of "GC" in the entire string

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated in the comments there are parenteses are missing in your code. Furthermore the statement seems to be wrong. Grep expects a regular expression. The star doesn't make any sense here. Instead you have to use `.*`. However, this means `grep` will match the entire string if it contains `gc` which is I guess also not the result you want to have.

However you can use `grepexpr` to search for the string `gc`

```
 >gregexpr("gc","aagccaagcca")[[1]]
[1] 3 8
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 2 2
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

The output looks a bit confusing (to me). However you can you can see that the string was found at position `3` and `8`

The number of occurences are then given by

```
length(gregexpr("gc","aagccaagcca")[[1]])
[1] 2
```

To make it match uppercase strings as well

```
length(gregexpr("gc","GCaagccaagcca",ignore.case=TRUE)[[1]])
```

Finally there is an issue with the length calculation if there is no match.
To solve this issue you need to use

```
 mtch <- gregexpr("gcxx","GCaagccaagcxca",ignore.case=TRUE)[[1]]
 if(mtch[1]==-1) 0 else length(mtch)
```

Comment: thanks got the answer.thank you so much

Comment: However, I still had to do a small update as it wasn't working in cases of no matches.